# Linux: super light-weight music player with http or commandline interface

Tags: linux, music

I'm searching a super light-weight music player which has a http and/or commandline interface. It should support very basic playlist support (removing files by id and adding files by path or something like that), play and pause and receiving the current status. It's enough when the player supports mp3, wav (optionally flac or flv). Oh, and I should be able to set the output soundcard.

On Windows, I'd use foobar2000. I tried VLC. It has a very good HTTP interface but is the complete opposite of being light-weight.

Comment: just use that one: http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=cplay

Answer (score 3):

As for commandline interface, [MOC](http://moc.daper.net/) should be enough. It is lightweight and rather convenient. Within some distros, it is available in repositories and thus easy to install. For all I know, it lacks the soundcard toggle feature, but I doubt it is actually available in other similar players and there are some, more or less convenient, ways to toggle the soundcard via command line (say, `aplay`).

Answer (score 2):

If you want feather-weight take a look at [mpg321](http://mpg321.sourceforge.net/). It *"is a very popular command-line mp3 player"*. According to its [changelog](http://mpg321.sourceforge.net/changelog) it also supports playlists.

Answer (score 2):

music player demon http://www.musicpd.org is like a headless winamp with command line, web and other frontends available for it.

Comment: Can you expand on this answer to give more details about the software?